# Is there a way to create a dynamically sized array besides using vectors or new?

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity

I'm trying to create an array of std::strings which will have length equal to a value read from a file (anywhere from 1 to around 300). I basically want it to work like

```
std::string arr[n];
```

However, I know that this is not valid C++ code. I know of 2 alternatives: vectors and the new operator. Are there any more?

I'm hoping to find something that will be faster than either of these 2 methods.

Comment: Are those methods really too slow? It is unlikely you'll find anything faster.

Comment: Are you implying that you want the memory allocated on the stack instead of the heap?  You could always just statically allocate 300 (your max).

Comment: if you want fast code the first step is get rid of `std::string`.

Comment: Pre-allocate a pool of strings. Take blocks of strings from the pool as needed. You will have to write a bunch  of management code to prevent fragmentation and overlapping allocations to make this work, and when you're done and know it works, profile the snot out of it to make sure it really is faster.

Comment: Don't forget to measure the performance of a simple `std::vector<std::string>` and compare it to your "highly optimized" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now for sure the maximum size, the fastest way would definitively be to allocate a fixed size array of this maximum.

In any other case you have to use either `new` or a container. There is no other way.  It's of course more convenient and effective to use containers:

- [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is one possibility. It's very fast for direct access to any
  elements, because elements are stored contiguously as in an array.
- [`list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) is another container.  It's designed for sequential access,
  and doesn't suffer from growing size.  And you can add an element in
  the middle withouh having to move all its followers.

As you see "slow" and "fast" depend on the operations that you perform.

What can slow down significantly the populating of a vector, is the need for reallocation when the structure is growing. One practice that reduces this problem, is to [`reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) space for a chunk of elements:

- For instance, you can reserve for 300 elements at once if it's the expected size.
- The vector size of the vector would increase as necessary everytime you add a new element.  As long as the reserved space is sufficient, there is no overhead. And if you reach the end of the allocated space, the vector will continue to grow dynamically through reallocation.

Comment: For a type with a non-trivial constructor, a fixed-size array of the maximum might not be the fastest way

Comment: Valid point ! I had primarily allocation+moving time in mind. But you're right : construction can be time consuming too.  So ... vector with reserve again :-)

Answer (score 2):

No. Vectors are fast. Initialise them with a capacity if it is known beforehand (your `n`) to avoid reallocation (`std::vector<string> v(n)`). Otherwise, if you have a compile time upper bound on the size, use `std::array` in [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

If you are *really desperate* - you could look into writing a custom allocator for the `std::vector`. See an example [here](http://warp.povusers.org/FSBAllocator/) showing some of the benefits. Perhaps you could make this have an internal memory pool so that it doesn't have to malloc/free memory across multiple allocations (if it happens that you use that type of dynamic array more than once in your program). Though I'd probably try to benchmark the code first and find the bottlenecks before I spend a few hours doing that...

Comment: Excellent !  But note that your constructor `v(n)` will create a vector of size n  (i.e. there are really n empty strings in it), so that you don't really know how much lines you've really read in it.  This is why I suggested to use `reserve()` instead:  the memory is allocated for n elements, but the number of elements is not changed.

Comment: @Christophe fair point. I guess that is a minus regarding usability? I don't expect there's a difference performance wise? What do you think?

Comment: I don't expect a major difference in performance for n==300.  Buf if n is 10 000 you would default construct a lot of empty strings in advance whereas you'd have no such overhead with the reserve().  More important, with your approach you'd have assign strings for the n first elements, and push_back() if you exceed n.  With the reserve(), you just push_back() consistently.

Comment: This is great. I was thinking that creating an empty vector and adding the strings 1 at a time would slow things down a lot (by having to resize the vector constantly in addition to the inserts), I didn't consider reserving a known maximum.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create dynamically sized arrays beside using vector
>   or new?

Yes.  Of course there is.  Software is remarkable flexible.

But first, you might investigate your plans to use std::string.  (Be assured, I recommend you do use std::strings.)

For example, on Ubuntu 15.10, gcc 5.2.1

```
the sizeof empty std::string type   is 32 bytes    
the sizeof empty std::string object is 32 bytes
```

using default std::string s1;

```
std::cout << s1.size() << std::endl;  // reports 0
and
std::cout << sizeof(s1) << std::endl; // reports 32.
```

Now, if you append 100 chars to s1.

```
s1 += stringWithSize100;

std::cout << s1.size() << std::endl; // reports 100
and
std::cout << sizeof(s1) << std::endl; // reports 32 ... still.
```

And, just to inform, in the earlier 32 bit g++ compiler every std::string was 4 bytes, regardless of content.

This size is independent of stack or heap residency for the string.

IMHO the std::string I have available is a wrapper around pointers.

But I think this is not a language requirement, just something you need to know about what your compiler / tool suite provides (now that std::string is part of the library).

---

I do not wish to discourage you, but guess what.  You need to investigate std::vector.  It has a similar hidden feature (regardless of number of elements, they report 12 bytes each).

---

My point?  There is no significant difference between your two choices, when they both lead you to std::strings with efficiency you seem to doubt.

And thus, why do you think you want to 'side step' these two choices?

---

Maybe the following term has fallen out of favour on SO. I have not seen it in a while.  But I will say it, anyway.

IMHO, your question is premature optimization.

This simply means, you really need to get on with it.  Don't worry about performance one can not know ahead of time.  Upon profiling, you might be able to identify that, by golly, the easiest way (using vector and / or new) worked plenty fast enough!

---

10/28 - update - an attempt to summarize

In the last 4 years I have seen std::string 'change' (in the 'what is visible at run time' sense) at least 3 times.

1. Ubuntu 12.10, 32 bit, g++, sizeof(std::string) is 4 bytes, 1 pointer
2. Ubuntu 15.04, 64 bit, g++ v9.x, sizeof(std::string) is 8 bytes, 1 pointer,
3. Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit, g++ v5.2.1, sizeof(std::string) is 32 bytes, i.e. 1 pointer and other things.

Each change reflects an implementation change, and very likely a performance change.  One can not know ahead of time how the next change might affect the performance of your code.  Hopefully, the libraries are always 'improving' in the way you worry about, but some of the changes address bugs, and 'fixing' them probably takes precedence over our worries about performance.

Comment: "IMHO the std::string I have available is a wrapper around pointers." Well yeah -- how else would it work? Same with `std::vector<>`

Comment: +1 for the premature optimization part, I think you might be right. However, I don't think you quite understand how containers and pointers are stored in memory.

Comment: @chbaker0 - I have not yet investigated the container code.  So I am just attempting to be honest about my understanding of these particular containers, as I have only inferred this 'obvious' idea.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @GreySage - I think 'not quite understanding' is fair, as I have not yet reviewed the container code itself.  I find containers very useful.  But the code style (of the parts I have accidentally seen in the debugger) both disappoint and discourage me from wanting to know more (yet).  Thanks for the feedback.  Are you preparing a lesson on "how containers and pointers are stored in memory"?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are asking for premature optimization. It would be simpler to just write your program in the most obvious way and worry about micro-optimization later, when you are actually able to perform benchmarks to see whether your optimization was an improvement or not.

It is important to *never* assume that a change will lead to a speedup; you must always benchmark. Compilers are smarter than you, most of the time; your attempted optimization may even cause a slowdown.

If you know a hard upper limit then you *could* do this, inside your function:

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(std::string), alignof(std::string)>::type buf[300];
std::string *arr = (std::string *)&buf;

size_t n = ..........;

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    new(arr + i) std::string;  // could provide constructor args here

// ...

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    arr[i].~basic_string();
```